# Hosting a SharePoint Web Application with a different from the Domain name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, url, web-application, dns

The domain name is **abc.def**

The web application hosted is "**GHI.abc.def**"

I want to host the web application as "**GHI.JKL.MNO**"

Is this possible, because when we add the name of the web application as an A record in DNS it will be "GHI.abc.def"

Is it possible to achieve "GHI.JKL.MNO" as the web application name, and how would I add it in the DNS

Should I extend the web application? or do a redirection to the URL?

Can I add this as an AAM?

Comment: Must "GHI.JKL.MNO" be available over the Internet or only in your local network? Are other Services hosted under the "JKL.MNO" domain (like Homepage under "www.")? Do you still want SharePoint to be reachable via current URL "abc.def"?

Comment: @Mheld updated the question. I have configured an AAM and added GHI.JKL.MNO in the Internet zone and configured bindings.

Comment: I still do not get the complete picture.. Yould you please focus again on my questions above? And another question: Which domain is your ActiveDirectory Domain - is is abc.def or jkl.mno?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not supported.

The new record you created is under the abc.def domain, so the FQDN is based on the domain.

What you can do is 1. create a new domain; 2. set AAM.

Answer (score 0):

This would be supported as long as you created a new forward lookup zone of 'jkl.mno' and added the A record there. Your Web Application would need to have an AAM that matched 'ghi.jkl.mno', of course.